# How can I install bluetooth driver(ASUS:USB-BT500) in Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: 22.04

I bought a Bluetooth-USB adapter at ASUS. But I am not able to install the driver for this product. I called the ASUS helpdesk about this issue. However, they don't have an agent who is able to take care of Ubuntu. Now I am stuck...Could someone help me?

> lsusb :

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 064e:c341 Suyin Corp. HP Truevision HD
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1532:006c Razer USA, Ltd Mamba Elite (Wired)
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 045e:07f8 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600 (model 1576)
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

> sudo dmesg | grep -e bt -e lue :

```
[    0.217009] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.244251] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4192.02 BogoMIPS (lpj=8384052)
[    0.371104] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
[    1.269500] pci 0000:00:14.4: PCI bridge to [bus 04] (subtractive decode)
[    1.269510] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window] (subtractive decode)
[    1.269513] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [io  0x0d00-0xffff window] (subtractive decode)
[    1.269515] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff window] (subtractive decode)
[    1.269518] pci 0000:00:14.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd0000000-0xffffffff window] (subtractive decode)
[    2.311555] usb 3-3: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   22.998539] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   22.998592] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.998599] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.998603] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.998610] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   24.275749] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   24.279876] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   24.281988] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   24.282007] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   24.327275] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   24.327381] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   24.327410] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 22496
[   25.270128] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e2f9f73
[   40.643497] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   40.643509] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   40.643520] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   77.917695] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   77.917716] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   77.917734] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   79.932291] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[   81.948406] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c52 tx timeou
```

> hciconfig -a

```
Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 9C:AD:97:93:54:54  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:2745 acl:0 sco:0 events:196 errors:0
    TX bytes:25729 acl:0 sco:0 commands:181 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT
```

> Driver:
> ASUS USB-BT500 Driver 1.0.0.8 for Linux
> Support kernel 2.6.32 - 5.7.1

Downloaded from here:https://www.asus.com/us/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-BT500/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136738/discussion-on-question-by-clione-how-can-i-install-bluetooth-driverasususb-bt5).

Answer (score 1):

This might help, although it doesn't quite work correctly with my Logitech MX Keys Mini (pairs ok, but characters don't appear when I type).

https://github.com/ARMmbed/connectedhomeip/wiki/Using-Asus-BT500-bluettoth-dongle-on-Linux-system

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1239235)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to follow the instructions of the link above. However, in section "4", After coding "hciconfig -a", there is no reaction.(suppose to come up with something?), then unfortunately it doesn't work..